# Max element in an array in dailogflow

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es

I am trying to calculate max element in an array . I tried this code but it is returning [object Object]
Is there something i am missing while doing in dailogflow.

```js
function studentgroup(agent){
    let games = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Star Wars: Imperial Assault',  votes: 3},
    { id: 2, name: 'Game of Thrones: Second Edition', votes: 4 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Merchans and Marauders',  votes: 5 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Eclipse',  votes: 6 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Fure of Dracula', votes: 2 }
];
    let maxGame = games.reduce((max, game) => max.votes > game.votes ? max : game);
    agent.add(`${maxGame}`);
    
  }
```

Comment: `maxGame.votes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply find the maximum element by iterating over the array.

```js
 let games = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Star Wars: Imperial Assault',  votes: 3},
    { id: 2, name: 'Game of Thrones: Second Edition', votes: 4 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Merchans and Marauders',  votes: 5 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Eclipse',  votes: 6 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Fure of Dracula', votes: 2 }
];

maxElement = -Infinity;
element = null

for (const game of games) {
  if (game.votes > maxElement) {
    maxElement = game.votes;
    element = game;
  }
}

console.log(element)
```

Comment: OP's code gives the same result, the issue is with `agent.add`

Comment: Yes console.log(element) is working fine.But the problem is with agent.add(element).Is there any other alternative because i wanted to give output in dialog flow rather than a normal javascript output.

Comment: what is agent here ? is it array, number, string ?

Comment: const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });  i think it is a string .

Comment: ok, use my code till console.log(element) and use this line after that     agent.add(JSON.stringify(element));

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `maxGame` is an object. Using your example, that object will be

```
{ id: 4, name: 'Eclipse',  votes: 6 }
```

But `agent.add()` is expecting to send back a string. The default "string" form of an object is "[object Object]", as you've seen.

You probably want to return something that makes more sense when displayed or read aloud, so it might make more sense for that line to be something like

```
agent.add(`The winner, with ${maxElement.votes} votes, is ${maxElement.name}.`)
```

which, given the example, would say something like

> The winner, with 6 votes, is Eclipse.